# Examples for using Google Admin SDK API (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk, admin, google-admin-sdk

We use Google Apps at my organization.  I am trying to just use my API key (no oauth2) to get access to users info through the Directory API in the Admin SDK.  I cannot find useful examples and the Google docs are buggy. I have had a great deal of difficulty with Google's API documentation.  Or perhaps I have to use oauth2?

Even if I knew some of the details about this specific API, I can't find  sample code for using these APIs in Python.  **Does anyone have sample code or links to real-world samples?**  I am new to Python and we're working on the App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use OAuth2 authentication, API key alone is not enough as you must authenticate as a Google Apps super admin or delegated admin (with appropriate rights) in order to perform Admin SDK Directory operations.

My project, [Dito GAM](http://www.ditoweb.com/dito-gam) was recently updated with full support for Admin SDK calls. It makes use of most (all?) Directory API calls. See:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/source/browse/trunk/gam.py

Also, if you notice bugs or ambiguities in the Google documentation, be sure to report them. It won't get any better if someone doesn't tell them about it! Use the "Report a bug" link at the bottom of all developers.google.com pages. It's very simple to use and pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: I reported 3 doc bugs so far.  they have a good system for that.   Thank you very much.  I am checking the code now.

Comment: What version of gdata is required?

Comment: You should be using the Google API Python client with Admin SDK, not the old GData library: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Comment: Ok, that's what I have been using in other tests.  I am still learning all this.  I got an error "ImportError: No module named gdata.apps.emailsettings.service" off the bat so I'll keep fiddling.

Comment: Sorry, I pointed you to the gam.py source assuming you just wanted to browse. If you're actually trying to run GAM, download it from https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/downloads/list?q=label:gam3 and follow the instructions at: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GAM3GettingStarted

Comment: Hi @JayLee , I don't get it .  "You must use OAuth2 authentication" for Google Admin Directory APi?   I think 2Legged oauth1 should work on the Admin Directory API, with just the domain's consumer key and consumer secret, am I right?  I am struggling to use 2LO on the Driectory API, but not succeed.

Comment: @JayLee Does GAM allow setting Gmail signatures? I thought it does but browsing through the repo I couldn't find the code that implements this. Would you be able to share a link?